# React component inheritance and ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm having a hard time understanding why this doesn't work

```
var link = window.location.href;
var array = link.split('/');
var sub = array[array.length-1];
console.log(sub);
var name;
var posts;
var upvotes;

var ProfileFiller = React.createClass({

   getUser : function() {

   $.ajax({
            url: '/profile/' + sub,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
               this.setState({user:data});
               name = data.local.email;

            }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log("error");
               console.error(this.props.url,status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });

   },

   getInitialState: function() {
       return {
          user: []

       }
    },


  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.getUser();
    },

  render : function() {
  return(
  <div>
  <hr/>
  <List user = {this.state.user} />
  </div>
  )

  }
});


var List = React.createClass({

  render : function() {
    console.log(this.props.user);
  return (
  <h1>{this.props.user.name}</h1> 
  )
  }
});


React.render(<ProfileFiller  />,
document.getElementById('profileView'));
```

I log it multiple times, and the array at my List class is initially empty, then it returns again filled with the element. I thought the ajax call is taking some time to pull the data which is why it won't work but it most likely has to do with the render and how it works, however if i set a global variable "name" and assign it to the users subfield where the ajax call takes place and pass that down as
`<h1>{name}</h1>` rather than `<h1>{this.props.user.name}</h1>` it ends up working.

I know the react way is to pass down props rather than setting variables and was kind of troubled by this.

Here is the server side of the ajax as well:

```
app.get('/profile/:user', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.user;
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        res.json(user);
    });
 });
```

**EDIT:**
**Some solution?:**
I was able to pass it down by setting user to data.local, it seemed as if when working with props it didnt work when you went down two levels of a json, I have no idea why. So for me this.props.user.email worked vs this.props.user.local.email. So i just set user to data.local instead of just data.

**Another Question:**
I also had another question, sometimes my array turns empty, and it might be because the ajax call might take a while. How do I work around something like this, would i say something like

```
if ajaxcall is complete/if success is complete 
   then pass down our filled array
```

But I thought setstate in our success call in our ajax would solve that. hmmm...
Or is there a better workaround?

Comment: Strange, but I solution I found myself is when calling this.props.users.local.email, it will run as undefined, however, if I set the state of user to users.local instead of users, and call this.props.users.email then the values return. I guess that this.props.{whatever}, doesnt look past two subfields. I dont know.

Comment: does this.props.user in List component exist when ajax response comes back?

Comment: Yea, it did. It returned the whole json.

Comment: So it doesn't work the first because of async. At the beginning, React will render components and call the ajax at the same time.React doesn't wait for Ajax response to execute the render function. When Ajax response comes back, this.setState will receive the data and execute the render function again. That's why the data is empty at the first time.

Comment: But if it would execute render again, why doesn't it even display the data when it arrives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
render : function() {
    console.log(this.props.user);
  return (
  <div><h1>{this.props.user.name}</h1></div>
  )
  }
```

React looks for everything in render to be wrapped around by a Div tag, after that the user can nest however they want. You could also write `var userName = this.props.user.name;` right under render, and call `{userName}` in the h1 tags instead. Secondly, the props past down don't can't print more than 1 level of depth for some reason. I don't know if that is a "me-type" problem or a react issue.

for example, it wont find this.props.user.name.firstName, only up until this.props.user.name.